# Adding a space in excel text

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2011

I have a list of ID's (e.g. BSAR1, BSAR2).How can I easily add in a space after each BSAR automatically.

Is there a tool/function?

Comment: Highlight the column and use replace (Ctrl-H) to replace "BSAR" with "BSAR ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If needing to do this surgically without using find/replace, I would use the below formula where your list of BSAR ID's falls into column A:

In an adjacent cell, such as B1, enter the following:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"BSAR","BSAR ")
```

From there, copy the contents of B1 as far as down you need it.

Cheers.